# How to Get Camera Angle and Rotation of Room?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am new on computer vision, I have a project that can segments floor after that it can change floor. I have good segmentation model but I don't know how to change pattern properly. As an example if somebody uploads this picture;

[image]

After that, if gives this image as input;

[image]

output should be like that;

[image]

As you can see in the image changed floor rotated and well fitted to room.
It can be any of room picture but pattern always fixed like an example that I gived above. I can do converting and integration operations but I don't know how to get room rotation and and camera angle automatically. I am open to any kind of suggestions or resources to  topic in computer vision about for thath kind of operations.

How can I solve this?

Note: Sorry about my poor english. I hope I could manage to describe my problem.

Comment: Omer, when you say "room rotation and camera angle", what is that relative to?   I think you mean relative to the "floor frame" defined by the plane of the floor and the direction of the existing floor boards.    So, you will first have to segment the picture to find the floor boards, then analyze the pattern to determine the direction and spacing of the floor boards, then reverse the calculation to render the new pattern.   Sounds tricky!

Comment: Agree with above comment. If you are only working on the floor, never going to worry about the walls and furniture, then you may not have to work out a true camera placement. What you need is to work out how to rotate a rectangular floor to match the perspective view of the floor in the picture, which is not easy, but easier than work out the entire camera and room placement.

Comment: This is a challenging problem and seems really difficult to handle